# Zero byte receives: purpose clarification

Tags: network-programming, winsock, winsock2, iocp

I am learning server development with IO Completion Ports.  My book, "Network Programming for Microsoft Windows - Second Edition", states the following:

> With every overlapped send or receive operation, it is probable that
>   the data buffers submitted will be locked. When memory is locked, it
>   cannot be paged out of physical memory. The operating system imposes a
>   limit on the amount of memory that may be locked. When this limit is
>   reached, overlapped operations will fail with the WSAENOBUFS error. If
>   a server posts many overlapped receives on each connection, this limit
>   will be reached as the number of connections grow. If a server
>   anticipates handling a very high number of concurrent clients, the
>   server can post a single zero byte receive on each connection. Because
>   there is no buffer associated with the receive operation, no memory
>   needs to be locked. With this approach, the per-socket receive buffer
>   should be left intact because once the zero-byte receive operation
>   completes, the server can simply perform a non-blocking receive to
>   retrieve all the data buffered in the socket's receive buffer. There
>   is no more data pending when the non-blocking receive fails with
>   WSAEWOULDBLOCK.

Now, I'm trying to understand this paragraph; I think I've got it *but want to make sure please*.

I understand about memory being locked if I post make multiple `WSARecv()` calls with large buffers.  But I am not entirely sure how a zero byte buffer prevents this.

I am thinking it is this (and would like confirmation please):

If I have `n` connections, and I post 50 `WSARecv()` calls with a 1KB buffer on each connection, that is `n * 50KB` total memory locked.  All of that memory is locked, regardless of whether or not it is actually being used (i.e. whether or not anything is being copied into it from the TCP buffers).  Hence if I keep adding more connections, I will keep locking more memory that may or may ever be used.  Thus I can run out, with `WSAENOBUFS` error.

If I however post a zero byte receive on each connection, a completion packet will be generated on that connection *only when there is data available for reading*. **(That is my first assumption, is that correct?)**

Now, when I know there is some data, I can then post a `WSARecv()` with a buffer of 1KB (or however much) - or indeed loop repeatedly reading it all as suggested in my book - knowing that it will be filled immediately *hence not remain unused and locked* **(second assumption, is that correct?)**

**Question 1**
Thus, if my two assumptions are correct, then I have understood my book :)  This means then that my server could, in theory, post a zero byte receive when a new connection is established, then when a completion packet is generated, read all of the data until there is no more, then post another zero byte receive - is that correct?

**Question 2**
However, isn't there still a risk that if I receive completion packets for **lots** of my zero byte receive posts **at once**, and I then go onto make **multiple** `WSARecv()` calls, that I will still end up with some failing with `WSAENOBUFS`?

Hopefully someone can clarify these two assumptions and two questions for me.

Comment: *I post 50 WSARecv() calls* - first of all post multiple recv on the same endpoint is logic error. must be only one recv per time. at second i think use 0 revc buffer is bad idea at all. only in ~2 time increase recv count

Comment: OK,I've read in multiple places that this is actually a good idea to post multiple `WSARecv` calls.  Can you comment on what I quoted from the book; not whether or not it is a good idea, but whether or not I have understood it?  Thanks.

Comment: no, multiple WSARecv calls is fatal logic error. if 2 recvs complete in concurent - how you determinate which is first and which is second ?

Comment: 2 recv io complete almost at once . 2 packets queued to iocp. 2 different worked threads remove this packets. all this is can be. question - how you determinate at this point - which packet first and which is second ? no sense have multiple recv on tcp socket

Comment: You add some sort of "ordering" to the receive calls, then process them in that set order.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2610/Handling-multiple-pending-socket-read-and-write-op.  It's fine if you disagree, but I just want clarification that I have understood my book correctly.

Comment: no, i sure that this is very bad idea. here described the same problem with recv order. i sure that need only once recv per time. this is absolute enough. just after socket connected - call asynchronous recv on it and with not 0 buffer. after it completed - just another recv and so on until disconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've done research into this along with experimentation and have found the following:

**Assumptions:**

1) Assumption 1 is correct.
2) I believe assumption 2 is correct.

**Questions**

1) I have tested this and this seems to work.
2) This I guess remains a possibility but much less likely than if I posted receives with a none-zero buffer.

Note that we can still raise the `WSAENOBUF` error when sending too fast; more details [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html).